# ¿Cómo puedo permitir al usuario descargar un archivo desde un web panel en genexus 17u2?

Tags: genexus

¿Cómo permitir a un usuario descargar un archivo desde la web en formato ASCII?

**HERRAMIENTA:** GeneXus 17u2

**REQUERIMIENTO:** Subir un archivo XLSX a un web panel mediante un objeto BLOB y descargar un archivo procesado con extensión ASC.

**PROBLEMA:** Utilizando las funciones DFWOPEN, DFWPTXT, DFWNEXT, DFWCLOSE se ha logrado procesar y escribir correctamente el archivo procesado. Sin embargo, este depende de una ruta absoluta para su guardado
y se desea permitir al usuario elegir la ruta donde desea guardar el archivo. Debido a la inexperiencia con la herramienta se desconoce el método para lograrlo.

**CÓDIGO DE MUESTRA**

```
Sub 'U_BotonClic'
    if &Carga.IsEmpty() //Ruta del Excel cargada al objeto BLOB
        msg('Debe de cargar un archivo de excel')
    else
        do 'Conversion'
    endif
EndSub

Sub 'Conversion'
    &Archivo.Source = &Carga
    &RDPE_XLS.Open(&Archivo.GetURI()) //Utilizar la ruta del excel cargado al BLOB
    
    If &RDPE_XLS.ErrCode <> 0
        msg('ERROR DE CARGA')
    Else
        Do 'EscribirASCII'
    EndIf
EndSub

Sub 'EscribirASCII'
    &ASCII = DFWOPEN("C:\NombreArchivo" + &FechaDeHoy + ".asc", "", 1, "") //Ruta absoluta donde se escribe el archivo, el usuario debe de elegir donde quiere guardarlo
    &ASCII = DFWPTXT(&Var1 + '|' + &Var2 + '|' + &Var3)
    &ASCII = DFWNEXT()
    &ASCII = DFWCLOSE()
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

En la descripción indicas que intentas subir un archivo a un webpanel...  por lo tanto se intuye que tu entorno de ejecución es Web...  (te recomiendo siempre mencionar detalladamente tu entorno de ejecución porque algunas cosas pueden variar en función de cada caso)

Siendo entorno Web, debes considerar que mucha parte del código se ejecuta en el servidor... y eso nunca será de acceso para el usuario...  incluso, esto mismo podría ser ejecutado en una servidor que ni siquiera sea windows...  por lo tanto desde la óptica del desarrollador, nunca podes asegurar que tu disco de trabajo sea la unidad C:.
por lo tanto la primer sugerencia es que nunca hagas referencias absolutas cuando creas archivos..

Tu codigo de creacion de un archivo en el servidor, que luego se envie hacia el dispositivo del usuario, deberia ser algo asi:

```
&FilePath = Directory.TemporaryFilesPath + &File.Separator + !"TuArchivo-" + GUID.NewGuid().toString() + !".asc"
```

&FilePath es Character y &File es de tipo File

El motivo de construirlo con un GUID es porque siempre debes considerar la concurrencia de usuarios, dando posibilidad a que muchos usuarios quizá ejecuten esto mismo, todos al mismo tiempo...

Luego de que el proceso finalice la creación de tu archivo... la descarga hacia el dispositivo del cliente será sobre la carpeta de descarga del navegador de su dispositivo o sobre la que el usuario haya configurado, pero no podes saberlo de antemano porque en todos los usuarios puede ser distinto. La descarga tendrás que hacerla mediante las variables de tipo HTTPResponse, podes hacer todo esto dentro de un procedimiento con la propiedad "Call Protocol" seteada en HTTP. (sobre un procedimiento, para que puedas reutilizar esto mismo desde algún otro objeto)

Recibes como parámetro el path del archivo creado.. y el nombre que quieres darle al archivo descargado en el cliente:
El código seria algo así:

```
&HttpResponse.AddHeader(!"Content-Type", !"text/plain")
&HttpResponse.AddHeader(!"Content-Disposition", Format(!"attachment;filename=%1", &FileName))
&HttpResponse.AddHeader(!"X-Frame-Options",!"sameOrigin")
&HttpResponse.AddHeader(!"X-Content-Type-Options",!"nosniff")
&HttpResponse.AddFile(&FilePath)
```

Espero te sirva...